# Finding values such that the game is strictly determinable

Tags: game-theory

Please help me to solve these two problems.

Q1)Find the range of values of p and q that will make the entry (2,2) a saddle point of the game.

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
          &player B\\
        2 & 4 & 5 \\
        10 & 7 & q \\
        4 & p & 6 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
Q2)For what values of p, the game with following payoff matrix is strictly determinable?

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
          &player B\\
        p & 6 & 2 \\
        -1 & p & -7 \\
        -2 & 4 & p \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

Please help me to understand how to think when solving this kind of problems.I got the correct answers but that was with a lot of guess and check and it takes a lot of time and I am not sure of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Q1)

On http://www.zweigmedia.com/RealWorld/Summary3b.html#sp I read that

> " A saddle point is a payoff that is simultaneously a row minimum and a column maximum."

So you must ask yourself under which conditions on $p$ and $q$ this is satisfied. Is it clear to you how to do so?

Q2)

On http://www.zweigmedia.com/RealWorld/Summary3b.html#sp again, I read

> "A game is strictly determined if it has at least one saddle point."

So from the former definition this is equivalent to the payoff matrix having an entry which is a minimum of its row and a maximum of its column. A systematic way to tackle this problem would be as follows:

- Consider entry $(1,1)$. Under which values of $p$ can entry $(1,1)$ be a saddle point? Define the set of such values as $P_{(1,1)}$ ( if it is an interval of values, you may denote it $(\underline{p}^{(1,1)},\bar{p}^{(1,1)})$ for instance).
- Consider entry $(1,2)$. Under which values of $p$ can entry $(1,2)$ be a saddle point? Define the set of such values as $P_{(1,2)}$.
- ...

Then the set of values of $p$ such that the game is strictly determinable is $P_{(1,1)}\cup P_{(1,2)}\cup \dots \cup P_{(3,2)} \cup P_{(3,3)}$ or shortly $\bigcup_{i=1}^3 \bigcup_{j=1}^3 P_{(i,j)}$.